# Converting byte array into float

Tags: javascript

I have a byte array: [93, 156, 244, 63]

I want to convert it to a floating point number, it should be ~9.8.
How exactly would I go about doing this in JS? I am rusty when it comes to bitwise operations.

Thanks in advance.

edit:
The array should be [92,209,28,65]

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the process and show your own attempts ata solution?

Comment: Chris, listen to Chris's comment :) - I assume you want to know how to interpret an array of four bytes (little-endian) as a single 32-bit IEEE float?

Comment: In what encoding `[93, 156, 244, 63]` is `9.8`?

Comment: `9.8` would correspond to `[ 205, 204, 28, 65 ]` (bytes of a 32-bit float)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it is a IEEE754 single precision floating number you might do:

```
new Float32Array(new Uint8Array([93, 156, 244, 63]).buffer)[0]
```

But it returns `1.9110218286514282` for the bytes you provided.

And you may see that `1.911...` matches those bytes: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049046057049049048050049056050056054053049052050056050